# Using StreamWriter(File.Copy()) to copy picture C#

Tags: c#, image, streamreader, streamwriter, openfiledialog

I'm trying to make a copy of a picture that user selects with OpenFileDialog into my folder. I have never done this before but I thought the right way to do this is with Copy.
This is code for StreamReader:

```
if (openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.FileName));

     destinationRead = read;
     uiInputSlika.Text = destinationRead.ToString();
     read.Dispose();
}
```

And this is code for StreamWriter:

```
destinationSave = "..\\bin\\Slike\\Slika" + name;
StreamWriter save = new StreamWriter(File.Copy(destinationRead.ToString(), destinationSave));
save.Dispose();
```

And in StreamWriter i get an error that says:

> Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.IO.Stream'

I'm pretty new at this and would appreciate your help.

Comment: `StreamReader` is a **`TextReader`** - it is for dealing with text; most images are not text, so `StreamReader` should be no part of any solution here; taking a look to see what you *are* trying to do....

Comment: what is `uiInputSlika`, and what is the `.Text`? if this is an **image**, I'm unclear how that applies

Comment: In uiInputSlika.Text I save path from picture user chooses

Comment: "In uiInputSlika.Text I save path from picture user chooses" - what does that mean? if you're trying to copy a file: `File.Copy(somePath, someOtherPath)` - with the file locations. If you're trying to load the **contents** from a file, then if it is small `File.ReadAllBytes` may help, or you'll need an image class of some kind. But you can't display an image in a `.Text` field, assuming that is a `string`

Comment: So it's immposible to copy picture with StreamReader? So what I'm trying to do is make user chose a picture from his computer, and then save a copy of that picture in a folder on my server. And then I can load picture in picturebox with path from server folder

Comment: You should be able to just use `File.Copy` for that, assuming the two file paths are directly reachable. You can use a raw `Stream` to read binary data, but not `StreamReader` - that is for **text** - but so far I haven't seen a need for you to go to that level, when `File.Copy` should work just fine here

Comment: How do i create picture in destination folder? Because with File.Copy i just copy this new picture over some existing picture. Is there a way to create a new picture file that i can overwrite with the chosen picture?

Comment: ultimately we're just talking about files here; if the destination file already exists, it will overwrite; if it doesn't exist, it will create new; how is this different to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wrote the path wrong :D everything is working great now :) Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
if (openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.FileName);
        uiInputSlika.Text = destinationRead.ToString();
        destinationSave = "..\\bin\\Slike\\Slika" + name;
        File.WriteAllBytes(destinationSave,bytes)
    }
```

You can also use File.Copy(). like below:

```
 File.Copy(openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.FileName,destinationSave );
```

Comment: why would you not just `File.Copy(openFileDialogOdaberiSliku.FileName, destinationSave)` ? there's no need to load the entire image into memory - heck, defer the entire thing to the OS